# Canvas to blob support in IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-11

I am using react-image-crop (https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop) within my react app to crop images:

I know that IE 11 does not support `toBlob` and was trying to use this polyfill: https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js

I ran `yarn add canvas-toBlob` and then imported it into my react component as `import canvasToBlob from 'canvas-toBlob';`.  I keep getting an error: "Object doesn't support this action". Is there something else that I should be doing?

Should I be importing the script into my main `index.html`?

Comment: It's a polyfill you shouldnt need to change anything. `toBlob` will work. Just import the polyfill

Comment: if you want to convert image you can use canvas.toDataURL() method.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: Also, if something goes wrong in your code, please add the error to the question, or else it's hard to help

Comment: Can you please try to add your sample code to reproduce the issue on our end? It can help us to understand the issue in better way and we can try to make a test with it to check the results.